# How to skip particular array index when using IntStream.filter in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I am learning and new to Java 8 Stream API,

I wanted to write a program to find even numbers in integer array using `IntStream`, so I came up with this solution,

```
int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

IntStream.of(numbers).filter(i -> i%2 == 0).forEach(System.out::println);
```

and this is working correctly for me.

but how can I modify the `filter` to skip certain array indexes from being checked from `numbers` ?

for example,

if i want to skip `numbers[1]` from being checked if it even or not then what should i do ?

because `i` in the filter are the values of the array elements not their indexes.

is it possible to do so ?

Comment: Instead of `IntStream.of()`, use `Arrays.stream()` - it has a version for `int[]`s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a stream of the array indices instead, and filter it, before mapping to the array elements:

```
int[] numbers = ...;
IntStream.range(0, numbers.length).filter(i -> i!=1)
    .map(i -> numbers[i]).forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you need first to filter some elements out by index, and some out by value, you can have one filter before the map and one after.

If you need to check both the index and the value in the same filter, then I think the best way is to create a class to hold both values:

```
class IndexedValue {
    private int index, value;
    IndexedValue(int index, int value) {
        this.index = index ;
        this.value = value ;
    }
    int getIndex() { return index ;}
    int getValue() { return value ;}
}
```

and then you can do

```
int[] numbers = ... ;
IntStream.range(0, numbers.length).map(i -> new IndexedValue(i, numbers[i]))
    .filter(v -> v.getIndex() == 1 || v.getValue() % 2 == 0)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: but then do i have to use `filter` twice ? once for skipping array index and other for checking for even numbers ?

Comment: Just have one predicate to check both conditions.

Comment: If you can write the filters independently, then that's the best way (one filter on indexes before the map, one on values after). If you need to check both the index and value at once, then I think you have to map to a data structure that stores them both. See updated answer.

Comment: actually i just need to use `IntStream` and `filter`, `map`, `print` etc...no need to get too complex....I have tried this `IntStream.range(0, numbers.length).filter(i -> i!=1 && i%2==0).map(i -> numbers[i])` but instead of printing even numbers it is only printing odd numbers...weird ?

Comment: sorry, i was checking `i` instead of `numbers[i]`.

Comment: No, you are showing all the even indexes (except index 1, which is not even anyway). So you get index 0 (=1), index 2 (=3), index 4 (=5) etc.

Comment: Yeah thanks I just observed that . stupid me...so if i want to use `filter` and `map` only then i have to use `filter` twice right ? once for skipping array index and then skipping odd numbers like this, `.filter(i -> i!=1).map(i -> numbers[i]).filter(i -> i%2==0)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Java 8 is complex, but its fun the same time.

Comment: Note that using `filter` makes the stream size unpredictable which can have performance impacts esp. when processing large arrays in parallel. So if you want to skip positional elements like in this case, using `IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(0), IntStream.range(2, numbers.length))` is likely more efficient than `IntStream.range(0, numbers.length).filter(i -> i!=1)`.

Answer (score 3):

A variant of @James_D's answer.

Imagine if we could avoid the usage of situational classes such as IndexedValue, because we are silly billies or something.

Well, imagine no more:

```
int[] numbers = ... ;
IntStream.range(0, numbers.length)
  // an anonymous class is defined at this juncture
  // for the sake of discussion, said class is named
  // Whatever (FF8 reference).
  .mapToObj(i -> new Object() {
    final int index = i;
    final int value = numbers[i];
  })
  // IntStream translated to Stream<Whatever>
  .filter(v -> v.index != 1)
  // Stream<Whatever> with non-1 indices
  .filter(v -> v.value % 2 == 0)
  // Stream<Whatever> with even values
  .mapToInt(v -> v.value)
  // Stream<Whatever> to IntStream
  .forEach(System.out::println)
;
```

Disclaimer:
I know this because I got bored once and tried it myself.
There is no guarantee that this code will work with non-JavaC compilers.
(Apparently, Eclipse's type inference is not as sexy as javac's. Whatever. [FF8 reference])

Comment: You need `mapToObj` instead of `map`, and presumably you would want `forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.value))`. However for me the compiler balks at `v.index` and `v.value`. (I had to try it...).

Comment: OK, actually Eclipse balks at `v.index` and `v.value`. If I compile by hand, it works fine (with those changes).

Comment: @srborlongan, I am sorry to ask that, but could you please elaborate your code a little ? i have studied that lambdas expression only work where the object of interface with single abstract method is expected, but when i look at your code i couldn't understand it.

Comment: shouldn't `v -> v.index == 1` be `v -> v.index != 1` ? if i want to skip position `1` ?

Comment: Fixed the filter lambdas. Also, the aforementioned code is supposed to be a translation of @James_D's answer, with the rather silly restriction that creating situational classes like IndexedValue is not allowed. In this case, I just created an anonymous class that is defined to have two fields, index and value, which is then defined on the mapping lambda so that the subsequent stream operations will work on an instance of Stream<MainClass$1> or whatever name the compiler gives to the anonymous class. Everything else is elided by javac (but apparently, not by Eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative solution, you can achieve the same result using iterators.

I'm the author of [Enumerables](https://github.com/Saulis/enumerables) which wraps iterable collections with functionality familiar from Stream. It provides a filter method that has an index parameter.

```
    int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    IntStream stream = IntStream.of(numbers);

    Enumerable<Integer> enumerable = new Enumerable(() -> stream.iterator());
    Enumerable<Integer> evens = enumerable.filter((x, i) -> x % 2 == 0 && i != 1);

    return evens.toList().stream();
```